# What is the syntax for an orderBy with an ng-repeat in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I reviewed the documentation

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy

but I am still a little confused so maybe the documentation could benefit from a really simple example as well as one that's more detailed.

What I have is:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data">
```

In the row object there is a property `row.num`

If I want to order my ng-repeat then should what syntax should I use. Do I need to orderBy `row.num` or `num`. Do I need this in quotes?

Comment: Did you try running the options you're suggesting?

Comment: @Dogbert - I will be trying but sorry to say my code has a few more problems and I'm trying to fix those at the same time. Those problems are making it so my grid.data source is not working right now. Hoping also that this post could be of use to others. I checked the documentation and from that I could not easily see what to do. It would be great if the documentation had a very simple example. Would be interested to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: Agreed that the only example they have is a bit complicated. Try this: `row in grid.data | orderBy:'num'`

Comment: @Dogbert - Thanks. Hope someone on the doc team is reading this :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to state property of the loop variable.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data | orderBy:'num'">
```